# Forcing removal of a comment hurting a company's reputation

Tags: discussion, support

I asked a question about where to report a suspected fraud job ad. I got the answer. However, in the comments, a person asked **where** I saw the ad, so I posted a screenshot of the **type** of banner I referred to. (It was needed to get the answer, I understood). The names of the companies currently there are blurred out.

Despite nags and (some) hurtful comments questioning my intentions, I made sure to stay neutral and not disclose any information about the conduct nor the name of the company. (The question asked was **where to report** and not **whether to report**.)

Now, I just saw that an user posted a name of a company (how he picked that one, is beyond me). He claims that we're competitors, which we hardly are since I know that certain company a little bit.

The comment is, in my view, immature, unnecessary and highly inappropriate. As such, it should be removed (and the user making it should probably be instructed to watch his conduct, because that approach is not worthy SO, but that's for others to decide).

How/where do I report **that**? Do I report that at all?

Comment: If it's _immature, unnecessary and highly inappropriate_ just flag it for moderation attention. If they agree, it will be removed.

Comment: So, just flag it and wait? I was thinking that the explicit name listed by that less thoughtful user's contribution might be causing damage **while** visible.

Comment: Any comment might cause damage while visible, doesn't mean we need some sort of fast track system for your particular case. What exactly do you want to see happen?

Comment: @Clive First and foremost - remove the explicit name/linkage from the comment. Other than that, remove the implication of **my** hidden agenda. It's kind of laughable that the companies I work work would be "competitors" to them.

Comment: Which you can easily do by raising a flag. What's the problem exactly?

Comment: @Clive The problem is as I described in my comment (second from the top). I'm trying to be considerate of that explicitly mentioned company. In fact, I'm getting the impression that I'm being questioned and it doesn't feel polite.

Comment: You've been given the answer. Flag. That's all. Use the "other" option if you want to provide an additional explanation. But that's all.

Comment: @Clive There's no need to be rude and diminishing. The answer to your question in bold is, once again, "because I fear that the explicit name mentioned is time-critical issue". Which part of "urgent" is unclear to you?

Comment: @Bart I can't flag it with additional information. Possibly because I flagged it with a default option first. The time-urgency was my foremost consideration. But now that I think of it, it's not me who posted the name, so I didn't conduct inappropriately. I must say, however, that both that and this post feel a bit hostile in response. I only tried to be helpful. I'm guessing there's something in the air...

Comment: Heck, flag your own post with an "other" flag and link to the comment's permalink. It doesn't really matter. Bottom line is that there is no "this is critical/urgent now" contact option. And all you've really achieved now is "that thing over there, look at it, I don't want you to see that". As for the hostility, your responses to others here and in the question you mention don't seem to do a whole lot to ease any tension. Flag, wait until it's handled, and in the mean time just move on.

Comment: No-one's being rude. If you mean the downvotes are rude, they're not. They express disagreement with your premise, that there should be some sort of special handling for when you think you've been slighted. We have a system of flags for content that requires intervention (a fact you've been told and have refused to acknowledge several times). If you're not satisfied with that, there's a link to contact staff at the bottom of the page. I'm not sure exactly what else you're expecting, because you haven't provided that information.

Comment: @KonradViltersten Flagging is the fastest way that is available to regular users.

Comment: @Clive Actually, I find **you** rude. Of course, now your **rude** comment is gone, it looks less so. But I found your formulation diminishing and impolite (not to mention repetitive and unnecessary).

Comment: Perhaps you should chill out, step away from the computer for a bit, and come back when you've had a chance to put things into perspective. You seem to be be getting quite worked up over what is essentially nothing

Comment: Oh come on @KonradViltersten, drop it already. Flag, contact, mail, whatever. But give it a rest. Nothing productive is going to come from debating who is or isn't rude or impolite or how feelings were hurt. Do whatever it is you feel you need to do to get the issue resolved by those who can and let that be it.

Comment: @Bart I've been instructed to only flag the regarded comments, not others, but I'm willing to follow your advice. As for the hostility, I'm sorry to hear that you perceive it that way and I'll try to improve. It's just difficult to reply with kindness when talked down to. But you're right - just because someone is rude to you first, doesn't imply you should be rude back. Feel free to point out where I went too far and I'll be happy to apologize. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @Bart I've flagged already, according to the advice. As for dropping it, I'm all for it. I think we both agree that there are better things to do. Perhaps some folks are having a bad day. No point being triggered by that. True... However, I'll never accept mobbing and rudeness. SO is way to fine institution, hehe. But since the rude comment is gone now, I'm good.

Comment: @Clive Yes, I agree with you. I appreciate you retracting that comment too. Let's all take a lunch or a short break and calm down. :)

Answer (score 7):

You identified the company yourself by posting a screenshot that together with your profile makes it very easy to get to the actual Careers ad. Or at least that is what it looks like, you might not have posted the actual ad, but that is far from obvious. And there is an ad in your screenshot in the same city as your profile location. If you used another ad in your screenshot, you accidentally suggested that this unrelated company is the object of your post.

I generally agree that naming the company might not be a good idea, but mainly because I have no idea if you're right with your accusation or not. You didn't provide any detail, just a very vague accusation. That kind of "they're doing something wrong, but I'm not telling you what" is rather annoying to readers.

I would either post details of the incident, without naming the company at all or providing any hints to their identity if you wish, or handle it entirely in private by contacting SE. This semi-public version is the worst of both worlds.

You can flag the comment to get it deleted, but I'm not sure the SO mods would oblige.

Comment: Admittedly, I failed in conveying the actual question that time. I meant to learn **how** to report it (and do so **privately**, just as you say). Didn't know there was something called Careers. To be fair, if I'd ask "*where to report a fraud*", I'd probably get criticized for being to vague. If I gave more details, I'd be criticized for bad-mouthing or something else. I regret that it wasn't well received but I also feel that people just assumed that I want to make accusations, instead of giving me the benefit of doubt.

Comment: How on Earth did I identified any company? The names is blurred. I never mentioned it by name nor said it was one of the listed. There are two different ones there. I also say that the company I mean, has been advertising for a long time while the screen is taken just the other day. This feel like a paranoia...

Comment: *"Or at least that is what it looks like, you might not have posted the actual ad, but that is far from obvious."* @KonradViltersten

Comment: @Bart Actually, I said to ChrisHayes "*Good point. I just took a random screenshot. I'll blur those but it doesn't mean it is or isn't any of them.*". I believe it's clear that I didn't imply anybody there.